# Possible to find height of a div and apply to top position of another div

Tags: jquery

Title pretty much speaks for itself...I need to find the height of a div and apply to the top position of another div.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$('.frame2').top($('.frame1').height());
```

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, `Top` is not a valid Jquery function, in order to set any style for elements using jquery you have to use [**`.css()`**](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Try,

```
$('.frame2').css('top',$('.frame1').height());
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the height values of 2 divs and apply it to css top position? Something link this: [$('.horizScroll').css('top',$('.frame').height() + $('.frame1').height());]